# Outlook Add-In dont show up on mobile

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I developed an Add-In for Outlook. I distributed this Add-In via the Office365 Admin Panel in my organization. I worked without any problem on all mail accounts in native Mac and Windows clients and Web Frontend.

The problem is that is Add-In is not showing up on Outlook for iOS and Android. I've configured the MobileFormFactor in my Manifest, see below.

What do I need that I can use my Add-In also on mobile?
Are there some extra settings I need to do?

Thanks for any help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
  xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="MailApp">

  <Id>e10f7be1-f108-4275-9387-ee5d8fa30c82</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Company</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>de-DE</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="DisplayName" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Description"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://[...]/assets/icon-80.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://[...]/assets/hi-res-icon.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://[...]" />

  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>sosafe.de</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>

  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>

  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.5" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>

  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://[...]?code=LICENSE"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.5">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>

    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>

    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://[...]/assets/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://[...]/assets/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://[...]/assets/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="https://[...]?code=LICENSE"/>
        <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://[...]?code=LICENSE"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="Phish Alert"/>
        <bt:String id="customTabLabel" DefaultValue="Phish Alert"/>
        <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Phish Alert Report"/>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Phish Alert Report"/>
        <bt:String id="phishAlert" DefaultValue="Phish Alert"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Report Phishing Emails"/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>

    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.5">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">

          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                  <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                    <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                      <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>

          <MobileFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />
              <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MobileMessageReadCommandSurface">
                <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                  <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                  <Control xsi:type="MobileButton" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                    <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                    <Icon xsi:type="bt:MobileIconList">
                      <bt:Image size="25" scale="1" resid="icon25" />
                      <bt:Image size="25" scale="2" resid="icon25" />
                      <bt:Image size="25" scale="3" resid="icon25" />

                      <bt:Image size="32" scale="1" resid="icon32" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" scale="2" resid="icon32" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" scale="3" resid="icon32" />

                      <bt:Image size="48" scale="1" resid="icon48" />
                      <bt:Image size="48" scale="2" resid="icon48" />
                      <bt:Image size="48" scale="3" resid="icon48" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </ExtensionPoint>
            </MobileFormFactor>

        </Host>
      </Hosts>

      <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
          <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://[...]/assets/icon-16.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="icon25" DefaultValue="https://[...]/assets/icon-25.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://[...]/assets/icon-32.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="icon48" DefaultValue="https://[...]/assets/icon-48.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://[...]/assets/icon-80.png"/>
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="https://[...]?code=LICENSE"/>
          <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://[...]?code=LICENSE"/>
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="groupLabel"/>
          <bt:String id="customTabLabel" DefaultValue="customTabLabel"/>
          <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="paneReadButtonLabel"/>
          <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="paneReadSuperTipTitle"/>
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
          <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="paneReadSuperTipDescription"/>
        </bt:LongStrings>
      </Resources>

    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: Can you please share the complete manifest file with us?

Comment: @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility I've added the complete manifest file.

Comment: Looks like we have a bug on our side. Meanwhile, can you please use SourceLocation tag in mobile form factor as 
<SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" > </SourceLocation>

Comment: @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility Thanks! It works now.